# Use reducer method on redux-orm schema instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-orm

I am using redux-orm to create models for normalization and denormalization. I find that when I create a schema, I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Schema has been renamed to ORM. Please import ORM instead of Schema from Redux-ORM
```

I have used both the `0.90-rc1` which is the version installed by default as well as `0.8.4

when running this code:

```
import { Schema } from 'redux-orm'
import Todo from './Todo'
import Tag from './Tag'
import User from './User'

const schema = new Schema()
schema.register(Todo, Tag, User)

export default schema
```

However I find that the documentation and code for schemas within redux-orm is still in existance.

If I switch from

```
import { Schema } from 'redux-orm'
```

to

```
import { ORM as Schema } from 'redux-orm'
```

the code works but I get an error specifying that `reducer` method is not defined here:

```
import { schema } from './models' 

console.log(schema)

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  orm: schema.reducer(),
  selectedUserId: selectedUserIdReducer
})
```

Most of the code is based of the [primer here](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm-primer)

My Models look like this:

**ValidatingModel.js**

```
import { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Model } from 'redux-orm'
import propTypesMixin from 'redux-orm-proptypes'

const ValidatingModel = propTypesMixin(Model)

export default ValidatingModel
```

**Todo.js**

```
import { fk, many } from 'redux-orm'
import { PropTypes } from 'react'
import ValidatingModel from './ValidatingModel'
import User from './User'
import Tag from './Tag'
import { CREATE_TODO, MARK_DONE, DELETE_TODO, ADD_TAG_TO_TODO, REMOVE_TAG_FROM_TODO } from '../actionTypes'
export default class Todo extends ValidatingModel {
  static reducer (state, action, Todo, session) {
    const { payload, type } = action
    switch (type) {
      case CREATE_TODO:
        const tagIds = payload.tags.split(',').map(str => str.trim())
        const props = Object.assign({}, payload, { tags: tagIds })
        Todo.create(props)
        break
      case MARK_DONE:
        Todo.withId(payload).set({ done: true })
        break
      case DELETE_TODO:
        Todo.withId(payload).delete()
        break
      case ADD_TAG_TO_TODO:
        Todo.withId(payload.todo).tags.add(payload.tag)
        break
      case REMOVE_TAG_FROM_TODO:
        Todo.withId(payload.todo).tags.remove(payload.tag)
        break
    }
  }
}

Todo.modelName = 'Todo'

Todo.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  done: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.oneOf([PropTypes.instanceOf(User), PropTypes.number]),
  tags: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOf([
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.instanceOf(Tag)
  ]))
}

Todo.defaultProps = {
  done: false
}

Todo.fields = {
  user: fk('User', 'todos'),
  tags: many('Tag', 'todos')
}
```

**Tag.js**

```
import ValidatingModel from './ValidatingModel'
import { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { CREATE_TODO, ADD_TAG_TO_TODO } from '../actionTypes'

export default class Tag extends ValidatingModel {
  static reducer (state, action, Tag, session) {
    const { payload, type } = action
    switch (type) {
      case CREATE_TODO:
        const tags = payload.tags.split(',')
        const trimmed = tags.map(name => name.trim())
        trimmed.forEach(name => Tag.create(name))
        break
      case ADD_TAG_TO_TODO:
        if (!Tag.filter({ name: payload.tag }).exists()) {
          Tag.create({ name: payload.tag })
        }
        break
    }
  }
}

Tag.modelName = 'Tag'

Tag.backend = {
  idAttribute: 'name'
}

Tag.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
}
```

This is the **User** model, I have added a no-op reducer after seeing @squiroid original answer

```
import ValidatingModel from './ValidatingModel'
import { PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class User extends ValidatingModel {
  static reducer (state, action, User, session) {
    return state
  }
}

User.modelName = 'User'

User.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number,
  name: PropTypes.string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I needed to use `ORM` instead of the `Schema`. So I changed the import for `Schema` to:

```
import { ORM as Schema } from 'redux-orm'
```

Secondly, I had to change the signature of the reducer to:

```
static reducer (action, SessionSpecificModel, session)
```

> the redux-orm docs have been updated, the second argument is not the state of the reducer but a session specific model.

from the signature in the documentation:

```
static reducer (state, action, Model, session)
```

Thirdly, I had to change the code in the `todo` to use `toRefArray` or `toModelArray` in order to call `map` on a list of `Todo` and `Tag` instances:

```
return orm.Todo.filter({ user: userId }).toModelArray().map(todo => {
  const obj = Object.assign({}, todo.ref)
  obj.tags = todo.tags.toRefArray().map(tag => tag.name)
  return obj
})
```

Fourth, I had to resolve the `Model` class from `session` instance.

I am still finding issues with creating a `Todo` where:

```
session.Todo.create(props)
```

throws the `error`:

Invalid prop `tags[0]` supplied to `Todo.create`.

when called with the `props`:

```
{
 "text":"Test my data",
 "tags":[
   "urgent",
   "personal"
  ],
  "user":0
}
```

The validations seem to be interfering with creating the model. When creating the tags, specify the `PropTypes` to be:

```
const { string, number, arrayOf oneOfType, instanceOf } = PropTypes
Todo.propTypes = {
   text: string,
   user: oneOfType([
      number,
      instanceOf(User)
   ]),
   tags: oneOfType([
      arrayOf(string),
      arrayOf(
        instanceOf(Tag)
      )
   ])
}
```

In redux-orm when bootstrapping or creating models, you can either provide the id or the instance of the model to the related property. Thus, it would be nessecary to ensure that both are accepted by the `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your code it seems like you have missed the code of defining the reducer in your models `(TODO, TAG, USER)`.

As per the documentation [here](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm-primer).

You need to have one static method inside each model.

`static reducer(state, action, Tag)
static reducer(state, action, TODO) 
static reducer(state, action, USER)`

Comment: I added the models to the question, as you can see I have defined a reducer per model.

Answer (score 0):

For further reading about migration from redux-orm 0.8 to 0.9 check out this guide from the developer:
https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm/wiki/0.9-Migration-Guide

The README on the github repo is behind, but surprisingly the npm README is updated to 0.9, despite the PR for 0.9 not merged in yet. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-orm